# Generate combinations in SQL

Tags: sql, combinations

I'm trying to write a select query for populating all the combinations of multiple variables.

My data is in the following format

```
______________________________
|    Variable    |    Value    |
|----------------|-------------|
| variable_one   | var_1_val_1 |
| variable_one   | var_1_val_2 |

| variable_two   | var_2_val_1 |
| variable_two   | var_2_val_2 |

| variable_three | var_3_val_1 |
| variable_three | var_3_val_2 |
-------------------------------
```

NB: I have a variable number of variables and a variable number of values per variable (*ie: the query should not depend on the number of variables or their values*).

I need either a single select query or a query that can load the output into a temp table (*ie: with a loop*) with all the combinations of these variable values in the following format, the combination id has to be generated on the go to represent each combination.

```
_________________________________________________
| CombinationID  |    Variable    |    Value    |
|----------------|----------------|-------------|
| comb_1         | variable_one   | var_1_val_1 |
| comb_1         | variable_two   | var_2_val_1 | 
| comb_1         | variable_three | var_3_val_1 |

| comb_2         | variable_one   | var_1_val_1 |
| comb_2         | variable_two   | var_2_val_1 |
| comb_2         | variable_three | var_3_val_2 |

| comb_3         | variable_one   | var_1_val_1 |
| comb_3         | variable_two   | var_2_val_2 | 
| comb_3         | variable_three | var_3_val_1 |

| comb_4         | variable_one   | var_1_val_1 |
| comb_4         | variable_two   | var_2_val_2 | 
| comb_4         | variable_three | var_3_val_2 |

| comb_5         | variable_one   | var_1_val_2 |
| comb_5         | variable_two   | var_2_val_1 | 
| comb_5         | variable_three | var_3_val_1 |

| comb_6         | variable_one   | var_1_val_2 |
| comb_6         | variable_two   | var_2_val_1 |
| comb_6         | variable_three | var_3_val_2 |

| comb_7         | variable_one   | var_1_val_2 |
| comb_7         | variable_two   | var_2_val_2 | 
| comb_7         | variable_three | var_3_val_1 |

| comb_8         | variable_one   | var_1_val_2 |
| comb_8         | variable_two   | var_2_val_2 | 
| comb_8         | variable_three | var_3_val_2 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I know this can be done relatively easily at the application level, but I got a dozen of variables each having handful of values, they all end up being millions of combinations. It's really slow doing at the application level.

- UPDATE
  This is on MSSQL, but if another DBMS makes life easier, I'm happy to switch.

Comment: What's the specific database? This may be possible in PosgreSQL.

Comment: @The Impaler, This is on MSSQL, but if another DBMS makes life easier, I'm happy to switch.

Comment: Cross join (cartesian product) with self join is doing something like this. Not sure how I could do the CombinationID field though

Answer (score 1):

The combination is the *hard* part   (P.S. no definition for 'hard' here)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
   Variable VARCHAR(20),
   Value    VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES
( 'variable_one'   , 'var_1_val_1'),
( 'variable_one'   , 'var_1_val_2'),

( 'variable_two'   , 'var_2_val_1'),
( 'variable_two'   , 'var_2_val_2'),

( 'variable_three' , 'var_3_val_1'),
( 'variable_three' , 'var_3_val_2');


Select 
   x.Variable,
   y.Value
   --,X.R
   --,y.R
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By x.Variable,x.R) - 
       ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By x.Variable,x.R)-1)%(select count(distinct Variable) from Table1))  as CombinationID
FROM (Select 
        Variable,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by Variable) as R
      from TAble1) x
CROSS JOIN (Select 
        Value 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Value) as R
      from Table1) y
order by 3
```

In the output the `CombinationID` is a unique value, but does not increment with 1.

output:

| Variable | Value | CombinationID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| variable_one | var_1_val_1 | 1 |
| variable_one | var_1_val_2 | 1 |
| variable_one | var_2_val_1 | 1 |
| variable_one | var_2_val_2 | 4 |
| variable_one | var_3_val_1 | 4 |
| variable_one | var_3_val_2 | 4 |
| variable_one | var_1_val_1 | 7 |
| variable_one | var_1_val_2 | 7 |
| variable_one | var_2_val_1 | 7 |
| variable_one | var_2_val_2 | 10 |
| variable_one | var_3_val_1 | 10 |
| variable_one | var_3_val_2 | 10 |
| variable_three | var_1_val_1 | 13 |
| variable_three | var_1_val_2 | 13 |
| variable_three | var_2_val_1 | 13 |
| variable_three | var_2_val_2 | 16 |
| variable_three | var_3_val_1 | 16 |
| variable_three | var_3_val_2 | 16 |
| variable_three | var_1_val_1 | 19 |
| variable_three | var_1_val_2 | 19 |
| variable_three | var_2_val_1 | 19 |
| variable_three | var_2_val_2 | 22 |
| variable_three | var_3_val_1 | 22 |
| variable_three | var_3_val_2 | 22 |
| variable_two | var_1_val_1 | 25 |
| variable_two | var_1_val_2 | 25 |
| variable_two | var_2_val_1 | 25 |
| variable_two | var_2_val_2 | 28 |
| variable_two | var_3_val_1 | 28 |
| variable_two | var_3_val_2 | 28 |
| variable_two | var_1_val_1 | 31 |
| variable_two | var_1_val_2 | 31 |
| variable_two | var_2_val_1 | 31 |
| variable_two | var_2_val_2 | 34 |
| variable_two | var_3_val_1 | 34 |
| variable_two | var_3_val_2 | 34 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4772b020865a9ecfb91161f296318065)

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but this isn't the result set the OP is looking for; should have 8 distinct sets of 3 values (24 rows), you have two repeating value sets of 3 values (1.1,1.2,2.1 and 2.2,3.1,3.2).

Comment: @dogyog: After a closer look there is indeed an error... Combinations 25 and 31 are the same, and some other combinations are double too 